# Xamarin.iOS Error : This copy of libswiftCore.dylib requires an OS version prior to 10.14.4

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-mac, visual-studio-app-center, xamarin.uitest

**Error: This copy of libswiftCore.dylib requires an OS version prior to 10.14.4** occurs while launching the iOS app using Xamarin.UITest for iOS.

Environment : MAC OS- 10.14.4
Visual studio for mac (Enterprise) - 8.0.2 (build 23)
Xamarin.iOS - 12.8.0.0 
Xcode - 10.2

Tried multiple workarounds mentioned in Xamarin communities, neither worked.

https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/5816

Comment: Can you run these commands on your Mac and paste the results?

/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/bin/mtouch --version
/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/bin/mlaunch --listdev -vvvv

Comment: Thanks for the response @LucasZhang-MSFT. However I received reply from Xamarin team that Xcode 10.2 is still not supported officially. Solution: Latest developer build of Xamarin.UITest (2.2.7.2002-dev) package resolves the issue. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.UITest/2.2.7.2002-dev

Answer (score 1):

**Xcode 10.2 is still not supported officially.** 
**Solution**: Installing latest developer build of Xamarin.UITest (2.2.7.2002-dev) package resolves the issue. The package provides support for Xcode 10.2
nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.UITest/2.2.7.2002-dev
This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I just got exactly the same problem this morning. 
Visual Studio (pc) - 15.9.4
Xamarin Forms - 3.6.0.293080

For me it went away when I manually installed Xamarin.iOS 12.2.1.16 on the mac.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't worked for me. Got fix in Xamarin.UItest latest developers build  nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.UITest/2.2.7.2002-dev

Answer (score 0):

If you install Xamarin.iOS 12.2.1.16 like explained [in this comment](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/5816#issuecomment-477733801), it will work.